# how to show a json file in JSON format

Tags: c#, json, json.net, deserialization, restsharp

I am not able to see the data in this JSON format below. Although I have get/set but I don't know why or How to get the data to show in this format!

**Desired Format:**

```
{
    "cinemaSF" : [
        {
            "customer_id" : "customer0001",
            "ticket" : {
                "ticket_id" : "1",
                "round" :  {
                    "idticket" : "2015-01-01 15:44:40",
                    "pieces" : "13.00",
                    "rate" : "100.00"                    
                },
                "down" : {
                    "idticket" : "2015-01-01 21:04:40",
                    "pieces"  : "13.00",
                    "rate" : "100.00"
                }
            },
            "dur_info" : {
                "start" : "102.34",
                "end" : "90.34",
                "climax" : "120.50"            
            },
            "cine_event" : {
                "score" : "80.5",
                "climax_event" : [
                    {
                        "event_id" : "0",
                        "idticket" : "2015-01-01 15:44:40",
                        "pieces" : "13.00",
                        "rate" : "100.00" 
                    },
                    {
                        "event_id" : "0",
                        "idticket" : "2015-01-01 15:44:40",
                        "pieces" : "13.00",
                        "rate" : "100.00"                                                                
                    }                                                                                                       
            }           
        }       
    ]
}
```

Instead I am getting this format:

```
public class cinemaSF
{
    public string customer_id { get; set; }
    public List<ticket> ticket_cinemaSF { get; set; }
    public List<dur_info> dur_info_cinemaSF { get; set; }
    public List<driving_event> driving_event_cinemaSF { get; set; }
}    
public class ticket
{
    public int ticket_id { get; set; }
    public List<pieces> pieces_cinemaSF { get; set; }
    public List<rate> rate_cinemaSF { get; set; }
}
public class round
{
    public string idticket { get; set; }
    public string pieces { get; set; }
    public string rate { get; set; }
}
public class down
{
    public string idticket { get; set; }
    public string pieces { get; set; }
    public string rate { get; set; }
}
public class dur_info
{
    public string start { get; set; }
    public string end { get; set; }
    public string climax { get; set; }
}
public class cine_event
{
    public string score { get; set; }
    public List<climax_event> climax_event_cinemaSF { get; set; }
}
public class climax_event
{
    public string event_id { get; set; }
    public string idticket { get; set; }
    public string pieces { get; set; }
    public string rate { get; set; }
}
```

I am using the following code to retrieve the data:

```
string url = "http://XXXXXXX.php";
var client_cinemaSF = new RestClient(url);
var request_cinemaSF = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
IRestResponse response_cinemaSF = client_cinemaSF.Execute(request_cinemaSF);
var content_cinemaSF = response_cinemaSF.Content;
cinemaSF root_cinemaSF = new cinemaSF();
cinemaSF deserializePlayer_cinemaSF = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<cinemaSF>(content_cinemaSF.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(deserializePlayer_cinemaSF.trip_cinemaSF[0]);
```

Why can't I show deserializePlayer_cinemaSF.trip_cinemaSF[0]

Comment: You need a root to desearlize this. Your JSON seems to have a problem please have a look and update if you get any changes in the JSON I believe the end of the JSON shud look like this `}]}}]}`

Comment: Your JSON is malformed - there's a square bracket missing off the `climax_event` array - and there is no member anywhere called `trip`.

Comment: There's no array `trip_cinemaSF` in your `cinemaSF`. To get all the data from desrialization, your classes should have properties with correct name and type. Please review our whole class hierarchy.

Comment: First of all your JSON is invalid. Once you'll fix JSON format (try http://jsonlint.com/) then we might help you.

Comment: It is still not a valid JSON

Answer (score 1):

There are few issues which I found

1. JSON is malformed it should look like this

   ```
   {
       "cinemaSF": [
           {
               "customer_id": "customer0001",
               "ticket": {
                   "ticket_id": "1",
                   "round": {
                       "idticket": "2015-01-01 15:44:40",
                       "pieces": "13.00",
                       "rate": "100.00"
                   },
                   "down": {
                       "idticket": "2015-01-01 21:04:40",
                       "pieces": "13.00",
                       "rate": "100.00"
                   }
               },
               "dur_info": {
                   "start": "102.34",
                   "end": "90.34",
                   "climax": "120.50"
               },
               "cine_event": {
                   "score": "80.5",
                   "climax_event": [
                       {
                           "event_id": "0",
                           "idticket": "2015-01-01 15:44:40",
                           "pieces": "13.00",
                           "rate": "100.00"
                       },
                       {
                           "event_id": "0",
                           "idticket": "2015-01-01 15:44:40",
                           "pieces": "13.00",
                           "rate": "100.00"
                       }
                   ]
               }
           }
       ]
   }
   ```

Next we need to understand the hierarchy of the elements inside it

You also need a RootElement for the JSON to Desearlize it so it should look like this

```
public class RootJson
{
    [JsonProperty("cinemaSF")]
    public cinemaSF csf { get; set; }
}

public class cinemaSF
{
    [JsonProperty("customer_id")]
    public string customer_id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("ticket")]
    public List<ticket> ticket_cinemaSF { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("dur_info")]
    public List<dur_info> dur_info_cinemaSF { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("cine_event")]
    public List<driving_event> driving_event_cinemaSF { get; set; }
}
```

Now come the last part

Class `ticket` must have

```
[JsonProperty("ticket_id")]
[JsonProperty("round")]
[JsonProperty("down")]
```

and `Round` and `Down` can have

```
public List<pieces>
public List<rate>
```

Then at last you can go for

```
RootJson deserializePlayer_cinemaSF = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootJson>(content_cinemaSF.ToString());
```